# swapon makes Ubuntu to switched to read-only file system

Tags: 18.04, swap, read-only

I have recently observed this problem with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.
Normally, the swap partition is automatically activated during booting. But I realised it is no longer activated automatically. When I try to activate it manually using `swapon` command, the file system immediately changes to read-only. I've also checked the file in `/etc/fstab`and the file is still in its original state ( no modifications ).
Please can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: The Ubuntu file system is read-only by default, and should only ever be read only (only root can modify it). Can you still write to the home directory`/home/username`?

Comment: no, I can't every thing becomes read only

Comment: make a harddrive-check with smartmontools, preferred from a live-session.

Comment: @kofimokome - to gain access to your home directory again, please try running `chmod 755 /home/supdroid` (NOT to be run as sudo or it will break your system). This should update the permissions of the home directory allowing read and write access for the owner (you).

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted my swap partition as swap, then copied the new UID to `/etc/fstab` replacing the old one, then I ran the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Finally, I did a reboot